PyQt6 QThread not working with high computational tasks
I'm working on a PyQt6 GUI that needs to call a function from a pyo3 library in the background, which performs very expensive calculations on a very large amount of data (we're talking about vectors with a minimum length of one billion; the application is used in scientific contexts).
This function takes from a few seconds to several minutes to process the data sent to it. However, what I want to avoid is the GUI freezing and becoming unresponsive during the calculation.
So, I opted to use QThread, provided by PyQt6, and here's an example of part of the implemented code:
class FCSPostProcessingWorker(QThread):
    finished = pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, active_correlations, num_acquisitions):
        super().__init__()
        self.active_correlations = active_correlations
        self.num_acquisitions = num_acquisitions
        self.is_running = True

    def run(self):
        gt_results = fcs_flim.fluorescence_correlation_spectroscopy(
            num_acquisitions=self.num_acquisitions,
            correlations=self.active_correlations,
        )   
        self.finished.emit(gt_results)    

    def stop(self):
        self.is_running = False


class FCSPostProcessing:
    @staticmethod
    def get_input(app):
        correlations = [tuple(item) if isinstance(item, list) else item for item in app.ch_correlations]
        active_correlations = [(ch1, ch2) for ch1, ch2, active in correlations if active]
        #num_acquisitions = app.selected_average
        num_acquisitions = 3
        worker = FCSPostProcessingWorker(active_correlations, num_acquisitions)
        QApplication.processEvents()
        worker.finished.connect(lambda result: FCSPostProcessing.handle_fcs_post_processing_result(app, result, worker))
        worker.start()
        

    @staticmethod
    def handle_fcs_post_processing_result(app, gt_results, worker):
        worker.stop()
        remove_widget(app.layouts[PLOT_GRIDS_CONTAINER], app.widgets[GT_WIDGET_WRAPPER])
        gt_widget = create_gt_layout(app)
        insert_widget(app.layouts[PLOT_GRIDS_CONTAINER], gt_widget, 1)
        gt_plot_to_show = [tuple(item) if isinstance(item, list) else item for item in app.gt_plots_to_show]
        lag_index = gt_results[0]
        filtered_gt_results = [res for res in gt_results[1] if res[0] in gt_plot_to_show]
        for index, res in enumerate(filtered_gt_results):
            correlation = res[0]
            gt_values = res[1]
            FCSPostProcessingPlot.generate_chart(correlation, index, app, lag_index, gt_values)
        

The problem is that the GUI still freezes during the execution of the expensive function, and I haven't noticed any changes since I introduced this new thread. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Does this answer your question? What is the global interpreter lock (GIL) in CPython?

If your background operation does not release the GIL while doing its work, it will block the GUI, since the GIL is only given to different threads between python instructions. Using the multiprocessing module to move the work into a worker process is probably the best bet unless you can modify the processing to release the GIL

Another possibility is that the worker thread object gets destroyed prematurely. The Qthread destructor will then block, waiting for the thread to finish. I don't think this applies here but your get_input method does not return a reference to the created worker object so that could be a possible hazard

Whenever you're dealing with CPU bound processing, switching to threading (at least in Python) doesn't do anything useful. On the contrary, it may even worsen the situation. Unless you have more control over what fluorescence_correlation_spectroscopy does (possibly, releasing control to the main thread every now and then), the only acceptable option is to switch to multiprocessing.

Thank you, it was exactly a GIL problem. I was able to release control using "allow_threads" in the pyo3 code. Now GUI remains interactive
